How to align image at center using ExcelJS
here the code, which is insert image at last column in excel
      const img = new Image();
      img.src = reportTemplate.logo ? reportTemplate.logo : defaultLogo;
      const logoSize = 45;
      const imgHeight = img.width * (logoSize / img.height);

      const logo = workbook.addImage({
        base64: img.src,
        extension: 'png',
      });
      
      worksheet.addImage(logo, {
        tl: { col: tableLength - 1, row: 0 }, 
        ext: { width: imgHeight, height: logoSize},
        editAs:'oneCell',
      });

So I need to set alignment for inserted image at center same as
expected result or solution to place image inside the cell then do alignment

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
